# Move previous commits to another branch

Tags: git

History looks like follows:

```
master branch     1-2-3-4
                         \
feature branch            5-6-7
```

I realized changes 2, 3 and 4 should have also gone into my feature branch and would like to move them as shown below.

```
master branch     1
                   \
feature branch      2-3-4-5-6-7
```

How should I go about? Nobody else is using my repo, I haven't pushed the commits since creating the branch and all changes are committed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just delete the offending commits from master. They'll still be in your feature branch:

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard 1          # Replace '1' with the actual SHA for the commit 
git push -f origin master   # Sync to remote, if applicable
```

Comment: Or `git reset --hard HEAD~3`

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen: Yes, of course. If you know you need to remove exactly 3 commits. I prefer the sha, because off-by-one errors are less likely... but in any case, be careful :)

Comment: Good solution, upvoted. Just to mention it, you might even skip the need to checkout `master` if you instead move the ref with `git branch -f master 1` then push as you did.

Comment: @RomainValeri: Also valid. Although the OP says nothing's been pushed, so I added that final command mainly for the benefit of any future readers.

Comment: Thanks a lot, it worked well. I was unsure whether the commits 2, 3 and 4 would actually be on the feature branch as well after deletion on the master branch in this scenario when all history was linear, but now I know :)

Comment: "Branches" are nothing more than pointers to a spot on the tree. So you don't actually delete the commits--you just move the `master` pointer from one commit to another.